# php header() function won't redirect

Tags: php, redirect, header

I'm trying to post data from a form with insert.php as the action. However, I cannot redirect back to the index.php once the data has posted to the database.

I've searched through the following sites to find the answer:

  [Trip Wire Magazine](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/04/php-redirect-to-another-page.html)
  [Daniweb](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/405266/header-redirect-in-included-file-wont-work-in-pure-php-file)

as well as ten stackoverflow questions on the subject.

Here is the code for the insert.php file:

```
<?php 
include 'connect.php';
$id = $_POST['id']; 
$idea = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['new_idea']); 

if(!$_POST['submit']) {
    echo "Please fill out the form!"; 
    header('Location: index.php'); 
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_idea (`id`, `idea`, `time_created`) VALUES(NULL, '$idea', NULL)") or die(mysql_error()); 
    echo "Idea has been added!"; 
    header('Location: index.php'); 
}?>
```

From what I've gathered, the header() function won't execute if there's text output before it. I've tried this function without the echo "Idea has been added!"; and echo "Please fill out the form!";, but I still don't get a redirect.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

-MF

Comment: Header should be before any output.

Comment: make sure you dont have like a blank line or empty space at the top of your file, or any other files you require( ) or include( )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**work around method** :  use `ob_start()` at the top of the page

**other method** :  Please omit any white space before starting `<?php` or after `?>` in the page
and also use `exit()` just after `header()`

Comment: @Michael its all my pleasure to help :)

Answer (score 6):

From PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) :

**header() must be called before any actual output is sent**, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

And in your case, you are using echo before header()

Comment: This answer encapsulates the main problem. Use @diEcho's answer to get around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php 
 include 'connect.php';
 $id = $_POST['id']; 
 $idea = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['new_idea']); 

 if(!$_POST['submit']) {
    $message = "Please fill out the form!"; 
    header('Location: index.php?message='.$message); exit;
 } else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_idea (`id`, `idea`, `time_created`) VALUES(NULL, '$idea', NULL)") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $message = "Idea has been added!"; 
    header('Location: index.php?message='.$message); exit;
 }?>
```

Pass the error message to *index.php* and display it there.

Answer (score 0):

Don't print your output before header(). Store your data into session or pass it through URL.
Try this will surely help you .